# Eclipse fica caindo conexão ao servidor remoto (NET Virtua)

Tags: eclipse, redes

eu trabalho com eclipse conectado remotamente a um servidor.
Recentemente, troquei a internet daqui da Vivo (antiga GVT) para a NET.

Após o troca, a conexão do eclipse com o servidor não persiste - cai de tempos em tempos, me obrigando a todo momento reconectar, abrir o caminho (longo) da pasta no servidor novamente.

Isso tb acontece com a conexão pelo PUTTY, ou seja, não é uma falha do eclipse.
Gostaria de saber se há alguma configuração para que eu possa alterar esse intervalo ou retirá-lo.

Comment: Se o problema começou acontecer após a troca do provedor, só pode ser uma coisa! O **provedor**.

Comment: Sim, disso eu não tenho dúvidas. Rss.. mas a conexão não cai, deve ser alguma limitação de porta, SSH, ou outro que faz apenas o eclipse e putty reiniciarem a conexão. Como utilizo chaves privadas para conectar ao servidor, acredito ser algo no SSH. Apenas hipótese.

Comment: Já adiantando a NET faz shapping ou seja ela limita banda para algumas portas

Answer (score 0):

Isso passou acontecer para mim nas conexões via SSH no OSX High Sierra quando utilizando a NET.

Eu resolvi editando meu arquivo ~/.ssh/config e inserindo a linha:

```
ServerAliveInterval 60
```

Ele mantem a conexão ativa mandando um pacote keep-alive a cada 60 segundos.

Obrigado a [Rodrigo Calado pela solução no seu blog](http://www.rodrigocalado.com.br/saiba-como-resolver-o-problema-de-queda-de-conexao-apos-5-minutos-de-inatividade-em-acesso-remoto-ao-ssh-por-meio-provedor-net-virtua-no-macos-sierra/).